# How to crop all pictures in a folder and save it to another folder by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, python-imaging-library

I have a folder of photos and want to crop 2 corners of it and then rotate 1 angle 180 degrees for 2 similar cropped images. I have a problem with image rotation and saving. This is the code that i got till now

```
from PIL import Image
import os.path, sys

path = r"D:\Machine_Learning\img"
dirs = os.listdir(path)

def crop():
    for item in dirs:
        fullpath = os.path.join(path,item)         #corrected
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            im = Image.open(fullpath)
            f, e = os.path.splitext(fullpath)
            save_dir = r'D:\Machine_Learning\img\crop'
            imCropTop = im.crop((2125, 70, 2148, 310)) #corrected
            imCropTop.save(f+'TOP_Cropped.bmp', "BMP", quality=100)
            imCropBot = im.crop((2125, 684, 2148, 924))  # corrected
            imCropBot.save(f + 'BOT_Cropped.bmp', "BMP", quality=100)

crop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "I have a problem with image rotation and saving. This is the code that i got till now" *What is the problem*? Please read [ask] and *ask a question*.

Comment: What happened when you ran the code? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I can't save image to another folder

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I have changed some of your variable names to fit with [pep 8](https://pep8.org). Clear variable names help to avoid confusion (especially avoid single character names - my pet hate)

You will, of course, have to use your own directory names.

```
from PIL import Image
import os.path

SOURCE_DIRECTORY = "../scratch/load_images/my_images"
TARGET_DIRECTORY = "../scratch/load_images/my_cropped_images/"
directory_list = os.listdir(SOURCE_DIRECTORY)

def crop():
    for source_file in directory_list:
        source_path = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIRECTORY, source_file) 
        if os.path.isfile(source_path):
            raw_image = Image.open(source_path)
            file_name = os.path.basename(source_path)
            file_name, extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)

            image_cropped_top = raw_image.crop((2125, 70, 2148, 310))
            image_cropped_top.save(TARGET_DIRECTORY + file_name+'TOP_Cropped.bmp', "BMP", quality=100)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    crop()
```