# How to tell my script to process ONE particular image-file extension using PIL in Python?

Tags: python, image, jupyter-notebook, crop

EDIT: I changed the title of this question because I realize I simply need to tell the following code to only process PNG image files and nothing else. I found a few solutions but they don't work. Allow me to explain:

I'm having trouble when using this code I found on another author's question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68767648/how-to-crop-all-pictures-in-a-folder-and-save-it-to-another-folder-by-python).

In brief, I'm trying to take a folder filled with PNG images, crop them, and place the results in a separate folder; I am using this in Jupyter Notebook in Windows 11.

****I realized that when I copied all of the source files into a sub directory in my Linux root, Windows 11 or Linux itself created "Zone.Identifier" files for each and every image.
**
And this is where the script gets caught up. Instead of just trying to ingest the PNG files, its also trying to work on these Zone.Identifier files as well.

For a test, I deleted these superfluous files manually and the script worked perfectly.

Here is the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import os.path

SOURCE_DIRECTORY = "/home/andy/crop/nyc/"
TARGET_DIRECTORY = "/home/andy/crop/output/nyc/"
directory_list = os.listdir(SOURCE_DIRECTORY)

def crop():
    for source_file in directory_list:
        source_path = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIRECTORY, source_file) 
        if os.path.isfile(source_path):
            raw_image = Image.open(source_path)
            file_name = os.path.basename(source_path)
            file_name, extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)

            image_cropped_top = raw_image.crop((344, 340, 474, 519))
            image_cropped_top.save(TARGET_DIRECTORY + file_name+'.png', "PNG", quality=100)

crop()
```

And here is the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnidentifiedImageError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [39], in <cell line: 20>()
     17             image_cropped_top = raw_image.crop((344, 340, 474, 519))
     18             image_cropped_top.save(TARGET_DIRECTORY + file_name+'.png', "PNG", quality=100)
---> 20 crop()

Input In [39], in crop()
     11 source_path = os.path.join(SOURCE_DIRECTORY, source_file) 
     12 if os.path.isfile(source_path):
---> 13     raw_image = Image.open(source_path)
     14     file_name = os.path.basename(source_path)
     15     file_name, extension = os.path.splitext(file_name)

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/Image.py:3147, in open(fp, mode, formats)
   3145 for message in accept_warnings:
   3146     warnings.warn(message)
-> 3147 raise UnidentifiedImageError(
   3148     "cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp)
   3149 )

UnidentifiedImageError: cannot identify image file '/home/andy/crop/nyc/DUDE.png:Zone.Identifier'
```

So, my problem may have a few solutions which require a tweak of the code, but I'm not sure how to go about it.  We could either:

- prevent these files from being created (before I even run the script, during copying and pasting)
- ignore this ZoneIdentifier files through code, or
  **- select only PNG files to be cropped through the code, or**
- change the source and filepaths to a directory outside of the linux directories, in windows, my desktop maybe, where these zone identifier files aren't created.

I'd prefer just telling the code to only choose PNG files, it seems the most direct way. What can I try to make it work?
Thanks.

Comment: The solution may be here:
https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pillow-image-resize/

But I couldn't get it to work exactly with my own code.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to *glob*:

```
import glob

for file in glob.glob('/path/to/images/*.png'):
    print(file
```